# Accessing external database from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a simple PHP script that makes a connection to a PostgreSQL database. The Postgres database is on one of my servers (not Amazon's). I have tested the PHP script on several different servers and I am able to successfully make the connection to the database. When I deploy this script to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk the script fails with, "No data received Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

My question is is it even possible to connect to a database not located on Amazon's servers from Elastic Beanstalk? If so can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE (SOLVED):**

Solution:
 
1. From the aws console. Navigate to EC2 Dashboard-->Security Groups. 
 2. Edit the security group the relevant instance is using.   
 3. Click the "Inbound" tab.
 4. Add "Custom TCP rule" set Port Range to 5432 
 5. Click "add Rule" and click "apply rule changes"

You may need to reboot the instance after this, I did but wasn't sure if it was necessary. This solved my "No data received issue". I then had a new issue that turned out to be a firewall problem on the server and our network.

In addition I had to edit the postgressql.conf and pg_hba.conf to allow external connections from all IPs. I followed the instruction here for that: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/78A8EE7180F64BB9B80731343DC27C2D@toshiba

Code:

```
     <?php



  $link = pg_Connect("host=MYSERVERSIP dbname=MYDBNAME user=MYUSER password=MYPASSWORD");
  $result = pg_exec($link, "select * from course");
  $numrows = pg_numrows($result);
  echo "<p>link = ".$link."<br>
  result = ".$result."<br>
  numrows = ".$numrows."</p>
  ";
  ?>

  <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>key</th>

  </tr>
  <?php

   // Loop on rows in the result set.

   for($ri = 0; $ri < $numrows; $ri++) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $row = pg_fetch_array($result, $ri);
    echo " <td>", $row["id"], "</td>
   <td>", $row["key"], "</td>
  </tr>
  ";
   }
   pg_close($link);
  ?>
```

Comment: Can we see the code that you have, or a relevant part?

Comment: Added the code being used but as I mentioned this script runs fine on multiple servers just not on Amazon EB.

Comment: Not familiar with this environment, but maybe you need to configure a hole in your outbound firewall, for the standard PostgreSQL port?

Comment: That's what it seems like. How do you configure outbound rules for ec2 instances though? Looking at the security group configuration it seems that you can only add inbound rules.

Comment: Are you sure that your remote db server is listening on a non-local IP, as well, and that a connection can be made inbound on that server?